# Breaking Up words using C

Tags: c

I'm currently studying C and I encountered a weird problem.

I was trying to write a program which is able to takes input of a sentence and output them as separated words.

```
INPUT:   a bb  ccc   dddd    eeeee

DESIRED  a
OUTPUT:  bb
         ccc
         dddd
         eeeee
```

This worked well when I wrote the following code. However it works abnormally when I changed part of code to what I thought should work the same way.

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NONBLOCK 'c'
/* separate words */
main()
{
    int c ,lastc;
    int toggle;

    lastc = NONBLOCK;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == ' '){
            if (lastc != ' ')
                putchar('\n');
        }
        else{
            putchar(c);
        }
        lastc = c;
    }
}
```

It works wrongly when I replace the:

```
        if (c == ' '){
            if (lastc != ' ')
                putchar('\n');
        }
```

with

```
        if (c == ' ' && lastc != ' ')
            putchar('\n');
```

After replacing, with the same input, the output will change to:

```
UNDESIRED  a
OUTPUT:     bb
             ccc
              dddd
               eeeee
```

My Question: Aren't two codes do the same thing? Why does output differ? Thanks!

Comment: On another note, did you consider using `fgets()` and `strtok()`?

Comment: Why not using `open()` and `read()` ?

Comment: @PandaCool @ Sourav Ghosh Thanks for advice, I will check on those functions as well. I used getchar/putchar cuz I've juz started reading _Programming in C_. :D

Comment: `man 2 open` and `man 2 read` You have to open 0 take a look at files descriptor hope it help and good luck

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the else statement of the first if executes in more cases than before when you perform that replacement (before, `c == ' '` was enough to prevent the else case, but after you also need `lastc!='\n'` to prevent the else case from running)

Why are you even trying to collapse the two ifs into one? They are separate, one-in-another for a good reason.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I added `lastc != '\n' ` into the if statement. Now it becomes `if ( c == ' ') &&  (lastc != ' ') &&  lastc != '\n')`.  However, yet it still works wrongly...

Comment: Now you mess it up. I don't see any reason why you should collapse the two ifs into one, and if you managed to do it correctly it would look ugly.

Comment: I see. It worked well when I add another `if(c != ' ')` before `putchar(c);`          However, I thought when the condition of the first `if` is not met, it will automatically execute the `lastc = c;` instead of running the `else` statement. Why does it happen? And I collapsed 2 into 1 just to make it fewer line ;D.  Thx for help.

Comment: When two ifs are one in the other and an else runs for the outer if, the inner if doesn't affect whether the else occurs. Rather, in an if-else pair one of the two always executes. You cannot emulate the combination of if-in-if with a single if when there exists an else case.

Comment: The eaaiest way to see it is to reverse the condition. Version 1: `if (c != ' ') putchar ('c'); else { if ... }` (correct). Version 2: `if (c != ' ' || lastc == ' ') putchar (c); else ...` (what?)

Comment: Yes but it still results in two ifs one-in-another (kind of -- the second if is in the else case of the first one). @n.m.

Comment: There are three different things one may need to do depending on the character and on the previous one: print the character, print the newline, print nothing. It's really really hard to do with a single if-else that only has two branches.

Comment: @billz sorry, meant to comment on the main question, not on the answer!

Comment: @PaulStelian I see it now! That's why the first space can be processed correctly while the rest of spaces is printed out. When `lastc = ' '`, the program will execute `else` block which prints space. thx so mcuh for help. Problem solved. :D

Comment: @n.m. Nope ,thanks for answering! That's also a good way for me to understand! Now I know single if-else won't work for 2 branches ;D